# Implementing the interface vs a method returning an object that implements the interface

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface

I've been on an object-oriented design binge lately in an effort to better my design skills. This question is about a particular design choice that I see somewhat frequently, and don't understand the rationale. I know design choices tend toward the subjective, but I'd like to know what others think about this to find out if my design instincts are getting better or worse.

I was watching [Robert C Martin(Uncle Bob) -Clean Architecture and Design-2012 COHAA The Path to Agility Conference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asLUTiJJqdE). During the talk he tells a story about developing [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/). I'm unfamiliar with the software, so I look it up and find [the project hosted on github](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse).

While looking through the project, one thing catches my attention in the [`WikiPage` interface](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/src/fitnesse/wiki/WikiPage.java): the `PageCrawler getPageCrawler();` method. So I look up the [`PageCrawler` interface](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/src/fitnesse/wiki/PageCrawler.java) to see what that looks like. Upon examining this interface I think to myself that the methods in `PageCrawler` look like they would belong to a `WikiPage`, and that `WikiPage` could reasonably implement the interface.

I would think that separating the two might cause `WikiPage` to expose internals so that the information needed to crawl the page is accessible to the objects that crawl it. Also, the `BaseWikiPage` abstract class just returns a new `PageCrawlerImpl`, and there are no other `PageCrawler` implementations in the project from what I can see.

I've seen this type of code in other projects where a method of one interface/class returns an object of another interface/class with methods that can reasonably belong to the first class. In trying to see the intention of the Fitnesse developers, the only reason for this design that I came up with, is that developers who create new wiki pages by implementing `WikiPage` aren't required to re-implement the crawling functionality, i.e. the crawling functionality should be the same regardless of the wiki page's implementation. Is this the purpose for such a design, or am I missing something?

I found the [Implementing an interface vs. providing an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917584/implementing-an-interface-vs-providing-an-interface) question on SO, but it wasn't quite the same and didn't give much insight into when you might design something like this.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the Interface Segregation Principle in action. You say PageCrawler's interface makes you think "these are all things that belong in a WikiPage," but that's looking at things from an implementation point of view, not the point of view of someone calling WikiPage.

EDIT:
Maybe it's less about the Interface Segregation Principle and more about the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I didn't think of it that way. However, my interpretation of the ISP is different. I thought the ISP is separating responsibilities into cohesive interfaces and composing an object by implementing the interfaces, not necessarily returning an object from a method that implements the interface. In this case, I'm thinking that the existence of the `PageCrawler` interface itself is the use of ISP. If the `WikiPage` implements it, clients of the `PageCrawler` interface still have no idea that the implementor is a `WikiPage`.

Comment: Furthermore, it sounds like you're saying that clients of `WikiPage` shouldn't know about the `PageCrawler` methods (is that what you meant?), yet they still have access to them except now they depend on what seems like a superfluous message (`getPageCrawler`). Wouldn't this be better served by using a decorator, e.g., having `WikiPage` implement `PageCrawler` and then `WikiPage` can opt to delegate to a separate object internally that also implements `PageCrawler`? I guess my perspective is: They say a `WikiPage` has a `PageCrawler`, but to me a `WikiPage` is _crawlable_.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, some functions that are "associated" with an object will need to hold state which should be separate from the object itself.  In .NET, `IEnumerator<T>` methods are prime examples of this.  Their meaning generally derives from an associated `IEnumerable<T>`, but each enumerator has a state which should be separate from that of the underlying collection (especially as a typical implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` will have no way of knowing how many enumerators, each with an independent state, may be associated with it simultaneously.

A few more advantages of splitting off interface implementations:

- The split-off implementation can include members whose names mirror those of the underlying type but whose functionality is different.  For example, a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, but has a `Keys` property which implements `IEnumerable<TKey>`.  Both the `Dictionary` and the thing returned by `Keys` have a `GetEnumerator` method, but one enumerates key-value pairs while the other just enumerates keys.
- If the split-off implementation wraps the underlying object, and doesn't expose a reference to it but exposes some of its functionality, it may be safely exposed to code which is trusted with that limited functionality but not with an unfettered reference to the object.  In some cases, having an object to hold a reference to a single wrapper object, which could then be used to satisfy any number of requests, may be more efficient than having clients use the wrapper object's constructor to to create a new wrapper object for every request.
- Although neither Java nor .NET allows for double inheritance, it may be possible for each of the tightly-associated objects to inherit from a different class.

I'm not familiar with the particular types you mention, so I don't know the particular reasons they behave as they do, but the reasons mentioned are all common ones.